# mongoengine: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I got an error by using mongoengine and i don't know what's the reason ?

this is my invalid syntax error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/home/mictadlo/.virtualenvs/unisnp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 4, in <module>
import pymongo
  File "pymongo.py", line 33
}
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

with this code:

```
from mongoengine import *

connect('dbtest')


class Test(Document):

 tag = StringField(required=True)
 tlists = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Tlist'))


class Tlist(EmbeddedDocument):

 ref = StringField(required=True)


for i in [('test1', "a"), ('test2', "b"), ('test3', "c"), ('test1', "a"),
          ('test2', "b"), ('test3', "c")]:
    test = Test()
    test.tag = i[0]
    tlist = Tlist()
    tlist.ref = i[1]
    test.tlists.append(tlist)
    test.save()
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The code is not working in Spyder and PyCharm, but is working to execute it from command line. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I just copy and paste the content to the ide and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You got an `invalid syntax` error in `File "pymongo.py", line 33` with `}` .
i thinks you change it currently ! so see whats the wrong in line 33 of `pymongo.py`